# Standalone TypoScript parser library?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I want to integrate something like TypoScript in my actual web application (its not typo3-based)

I want to use typoscript in files, and then the parser will return me a configuration array

It is possible or there are something similar for PHP ?

Comment: Typo3 is written in PHP. Maybe there is a TypoScript engine offered by the software vendor? Have you contacted Typo3 for your support options?

Comment: nope, I will send them and email and if its possible, shoot the answer here

Comment: Well I'm sure they have a forum or IRC chat. Start with that. And check for their mailinglist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the **t3lib/class.t3lib_tsparser.php** class. Maybe you will be able to adapt it for your project. Especially its `parse()` and `parseSub()` methods should be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Check `TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\TemplateService`, but I fear it will be rather hard to use it standalone.

You will find the class at `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/TypoScript/TemplateService.php`.